# c# Array -> metodo que recibe un array y devuelve otro (Orientacion a Objetos)

Tags: c#

El metodo consiste en un array de Objetos(Personas y Puntos de interes) y debe devolver un array de Personas. Debe de filtrar el array de objetos y si es un objeto Persona, crear un array con todos aquellas Personas que se encuentre. Mi problema es que tan solo me filtra el primer objeto Persona (German,Iglesias,11) y no consigo que me aparezca la segunda persona.

```
    private static Persona[] Metodo(Object[] array)
    {
        Persona[] resultado = new Persona[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] is Persona)
            {
                //resultado[i] = array[i] as Persona;
                resultado[i] = (Persona)array[i];
                resultado[i] = new Persona(resultado[i].Nombre, resultado[i].Apellido, resultado[i].Nif);
                return resultado;
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```

Y en el main tengo lo siguiente:

````
Object[] arrayVariado = new Object[] { new Persona("German", "Iglesias", "11"), new 
Persona("Julio", "Cesar", "333"), new PuntoDeInteres(2.1, 3.2, "Alburquerque") };
            
            Persona[] p = Metodo(arrayVariado);

            foreach(Persona persona in p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(persona);
            }```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola tienes que quitar el return dentro del if, por eso siempre te regresa solo el primero

```
 private static Persona[] Metodo(Object[] array)
    {
        Persona[] resultado = new Persona[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] is Persona)
            {
                //resultado[i] = array[i] as Persona;
                resultado[i] = (Persona)array[i];
                resultado[i] = new Persona(resultado[i].Nombre, resultado[i].Apellido, resultado[i].Nif);
                //return resultado;
            }
        }
        return resultado;
    }
```